# WSO2 IS 5.10 - User Portal application missing in service provider list

Tags: wso2, identityserver3, service-provider, wso2-identity-server

My User Portal app is missing when I check the Service Providers:

[image: SP List]

But when I try to create a new one it tells me that it still exists .
[image: User Portal still exist]

Moreover, the User Portal works fine but I need to make some changes in the configuration.

Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Did you change the DB or manually changed some data related to the applications in DB?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Did you change the admin name in the middle by any chance?
One more thing to check would be to go to Users and Roles-> Role -> Application roles and see if you can find a role with name "Application/User Portal". If you can assign it to your current admin user and see if the application appears.